# Obj C - Is there a way to make a method return the method in which it is called?

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, methods

I want to know whether there is the way to achieve the following requirement:

First, there is a `methodA`, which takes an input `objA` and check whether `objA` is valid for the method. If it's valid, then it returns an object `objB`. However, if `objA` is not valid, it just returns `objA` itself. Note that even if `objA` is valid, the returned `objB` may still be the same with `objB`.

Then, there is a `methodB` and in the `method`, `methodA` is called. If the input of `methodA` is valid, the program go on without error. However, if `methodA` is called with invalid input, then `methodB` should terminate (a.k.a return with a certain string signaling an error) to prevent future crash.

The current solution that I could think of is to create a `(BOOL)methodAInputIsValid:(obj)input` and in `methodB` there is:

```
if(methodAInputIsValid:input) {
    obj objReturn = methodA:input;
}else{
    //show error warning
    return;
}
//continue doing something with objReturn and finally return some valid thing
```

A problem of the code is that `(BOOL)methodAInputIsValid:(obj)input` and `methodA:(obj)input` share a lot of code in common because there is a validity-test in `methodA`. So I want to use the validity-test more efficiently so that it will work for `methodB` and drop the `(BOOL)methodAInputIsValid`.

Here is one possible application that I could think of:

In a program the user is asked to enter a string that will direct the action of the program. However, the input string may need to be standardized such as converting all letters to lower-case and converting all single quotation to double quotation and auto-complete any missing right parenthesis or quotation marks. However, if the user is just entering nonsense that cannot be standardized, then the program should terminate and warn the user of the problem. The two methods are `(BOOL)isStandardizeable:(NSString *)input` and `(NSString *)standardize:(NSString *)input`. Because `(NSString *)standardize` already returns an `NSString *`, I can't make it to return another `BOOL`, right? So the following code is not achievable:

```
if(standardize:input){
    NSString *result = standardize:input;
} else {
    NSLog(@"unrecognizable input!");
    return;
}
//continue...
```

Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically, I'd just have `methodA` return `nil` if the input is not valid. This is a fairly common method to signal failure to a caller. If you really need the "identity" part of the method, just have callers do

```
id res = [... methodA:input];
if(res == nil)
    res = input;
```